# Can anybody help me decipher this Nginx directive?

Tags: nginx, configuration

I am quite new to Nginx and I have just found the following directive in a Nginx configuration file:

```
if (!-f $request_filename){
            set $rule_1 1$rule_1;
}
```

While I can understand what the condition is, for the life of me I can't understand what that set directive sets `$rule_1` to and what those two variables stand for (`$rule_1` and `1$rule_1`). I have tried reading the Nginx documentation but I'm still as clueless as before.

Any pointer or reading material is welcome.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

It prepends "1" to $rule_1 variable.
Seems, $rule_1 variable is checked somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. By looking at the rest of the code I was finally able to make sense of this. It basically checks whether the requested file is actually a file, if not, it sets $rule_1 to 1, since $rule_1 is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the rest of the code I was finally able to make sense of this. It basically checks whether the requested file is actually a file, if not, it sets $rule_1 to 1, since $rule_1 is undefined.